# Shouldn't the scope be isolated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two simple directives who generate similar elements in the DOM.

- Both have an isolated scope
- Both have an ng-click to a metod that displays a message.
- One has the ng-click declared in the html file and that one triggers the method in the containing scope.
- The other has the ng-click in the directive template and a click triggers the method in the isolated scope

Why doesn't both trigger the method in the isolated scope?

Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HOUpkkZtNAwJTHvpCuAU?p=preview)

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.alertMessage = function(){
    alert('I live in mainController');
  }
});

app.directive('isolated', function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.alertMessage = function(){
        alert('I live in the isolated directive');
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('isolatedWithTemplate', function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="alertMessage()">Press me</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.alertMessage = function(){
        alert('I live in the isolated directive');
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Html**

```
<button isolated ng-click="alertMessage()">Press me</button>
<div isolated-with-template></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer updated with corrections more info as pointed out by @Edminsson)

Refer to following link to understand the scopes - although the link does not explain the above behavior my answer will try to do explain.

[Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#angular-scope-inheritance)

Following will try to explain why the element with 'isolated' directive says 'I am in mainController scope' instead of 'I am in isolated scope.

Note the order of the two DOM element does not matter, neither the priority affects anything with respect to what we saw.

```
<div isolated-with-template></div>
<button  isolated ng-click="alertMessage()">No Template</button>
```

Each directive on the  element is compiled on the scope of the parent.
That means the ng-click got bound to the scope function in the MainController. The isolate directive does create a new isolated scope and the function on it but the ng-click is already bound to the function object $scope.alertMessage() from mainController.

Element with isolated-with-template is also getting compiled with the parent scope. However when it encounters the directive it has now a template. This gets compiled (to be precise nodeLinkFn. There is afterTemplateNodeLinkFn so directives with templates or templateUrls will use this). At this time the isolated scope has the function alertMessage from the isolated scope. Also know that the MainController's alertMessage was already defined on that scope prior to all this.

1) Angular processes the DOM depth first and links backwards

2) root of the template gets its immediate scope

3) when multiple directives are requesting scopes on an element you get only one scope

**What happens with scope = true ?**

In [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrmOQKMov0PPa2KeXiHo?p=preview) you will notice that the directive no longer says 'I am in mainController'.

```
scope:true,
```

You are actually getting brand new child scope. When a linking function is created angular knows about this scope being a brand new scope.

One trick for isolated scopes
Try assigning template: ' ', and replace: true
and you have your isolated scope in action.

[Isolated scope trick using another example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jXwrtG?p=preview)

```
.directive("client", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      template: '  ',//notice extra spaces
      replace: true,//notice this
      scope: {
        name: "@name",
        client: "=client"
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: @bhantol - You wrote "scope = {} still inherits from the parent scope only in a prototypical way".
Do you mean that the isolated scope inherits from the parent scope? Because in the angular documentation it declares that they do not.
"Isolate scope's $parent references the parent scope, so although it is isolated and doesn't inherit prototypically from the parent scope, it is still a child scope."  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: @Edminsson Thank you for correction. scope = {} does not inherit. The inheritance link is broken with {}. I fixed the answer which still boils down to linking with templates uses the directives scope. Also thank you for posting the excellent link. As to reason why directive;s scope does not apply to the element - I am thinking that the directive does not produce new HTML.

Comment: @DalbyModo Please see additional updates. Tricked the directive to use the isolated scope with template: ' ' literally blank. I am thinking this need to be reported to angular team.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button isolated ng-click="alertMessage()">Press me</button>
```

in this case the `ng-click` is independent of isolated directive, it will work even if you change html to

```
<button ng-click="alertMessage()">Press me</button>
```

so the `ng-click` above is not working on isolate directive but on scope of your controller...

the `ng-click` of `isolated-with-template` is working in scope of a directive..

Comment: Declaring the isolate directive in the button element creates a new isolated scope even though the ng-click is not bound to it. I guess only templates in the directive are compiled using the isolated scope.

Comment: yes you are right... ng-click is independent directive, which can have  its own isolate/derived/parent scope and its scope has nothing to do with `isolated` directives scope

Comment: @Dalby Modo yes, when templates are involved angular utilizes special afterTemplateNodeLinkFn which uses the current scope - at this time the current scope is the {} scope on the directive and it passes this scope. Basically bottom line is when scope = {} used Angular will extend the scope prototypically perhaps at a later point.